# how can I change the output of this method which uses a superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass, bluej

Hi I wanted to know how I could change the output of the display method so the output, which currently looks like this:

```
Leonardo da Vinci
40 seconds ago - 2 people like this.
No comments.
Had a great idea this morning.
But now I forgot what it was. Something to do with flying...
```

can be made to look like this

```
Leonardo da Vinci
Had a great idea this morning.
But now I forgot what it was. Something to do with flying...
40 seconds ago - 2 people like this.
No comments.
```

These are the two methods, which are responsible for part of the output in the superclass

```
public String toString()
{

    String text = username + "\n" + timeString(timestamp);

    if(likes > 0) {
        text+= "  -  " + likes + " people like this.\n";
    }
    else {
        text+= "\n";
    }

    if(comments.isEmpty()) {
        return text + "   No comments.\n";
    }
    else {
        return text + "   " + comments.size() + 
        " comment(s). Click here to view.\n";
    }
}

public void display()
{
    System.out.println(toString());
}
```

and these are the two methods in the subclass, which complete the output by calling the superclass above.

```
   public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + message + "\n";
    }

    /**
     * Display the details of this post.
     * 
     * (Currently: Print to the text terminal. This is simulating display 
     * in a web browser for now.)
     */
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(toString());
    }
```

Comment: Are you allowed to change the subclass, superclass and/or which methods can you change?

Comment: I can make any necessary changes to either class @BRNTZN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result you expect:

```
Leonardo da Vinci
Had a great idea this morning.
But now I forgot what it was. Something to do with flying...

40 seconds ago - 2 people like this.
No comments.
```

The value of the `message` is:

```
Had a great idea this morning.
But now I forgot what it was. Something to do with flying...
```

And the value of the `super.toString()`:

```
40 seconds ago - 2 people like this.
No comments.
```

Your subclass toString() returns this:

```
public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + message + "\n";
}
```

And your result is: `super.toString():`

```
Leonardo da Vinci
40 seconds ago - 2 people like this.
No comments.
```

and `message`:

```
 Had a great idea this morning.
 But now I forgot what it was. Something to do with flying...
```

Do you see why it is being printed in that order?
You can simply change the order to:

```
return message + super.toString() + "\n";
```

This will change the order in which it is displayed.

And have the value of the `username` from the `super.toString()` printed in the variable `message`

Comment: Thanks I get it now @miqdadamirali

Answer (score 0):

You can make individual methods for each string in the classes and call on them individually while building up your end String.

for example:

in superclass:

```
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getTimeString() {
    return timeString(timestamp);
}
```

in subclass:

```
public void display() {
    System.out.println(super.getTimeString()+"\n"+message);
    //or put whatever in whatever order you want.
}
```